# How to parse xml with namespace in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am having problem to parse xml that include different name space with xml nodes.
Here are the sample of xml string

```
<ArrayOfKeyValueOfApplicationEnumApplicationPermissionscE6Yi1yY xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
  <KeyValueOfApplicationEnumApplicationPermissionscE6Yi1yY>
    <Key>CoreAdmin</Key>
    <Value xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CC.CoreServices.DTO.ServiceMethodResponses">
      <d3p1:MenuPermissions xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CC.CoreServices.DTO">
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>1001</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>Business Home</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:PageId>page1Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Business/BusinessHome.aspx</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName>iconHome</d4p1:SUPageName>
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:DisplayOrder>1</d4p1:DisplayOrder>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>1002</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>Home</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:MenuParentID>1001</d4p1:MenuParentID>
          <d4p1:PageId>page1Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Business/BusinessHome.aspx</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName>iconHome</d4p1:SUPageName>
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:DisplayOrder>2</d4p1:DisplayOrder>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>1003</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>Business Profile</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:MenuParentID>1001</d4p1:MenuParentID>
          <d4p1:PageId>page1Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Business/BusinessProfile.aspx</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName>iconBusinessProfile</d4p1:SUPageName>
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>1020</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>New Card</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:PageId>page2Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Cards/NewCard.aspx</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName>iconNewCard</d4p1:SUPageName>
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:DisplayOrder>1</d4p1:DisplayOrder>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>1021</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>Personalized</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:MenuParentID>1020</d4p1:MenuParentID>
          <d4p1:PageId>page2Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Cards/PersonalizedCard.aspx</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName>iconPersonalized</d4p1:SUPageName>
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:DisplayOrder>2</d4p1:DisplayOrder>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>1022</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>Instant</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:MenuParentID>1020</d4p1:MenuParentID>
          <d4p1:PageId>page2Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Cards/CreateRequest.aspx</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName>iconInstant</d4p1:SUPageName>
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:DisplayOrder>3</d4p1:DisplayOrder>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>1024</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>Assign Instant Cards</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:MenuParentID>1020</d4p1:MenuParentID>
          <d4p1:PageId>page2Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Cards/InstantIssue.aspx</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName>iconAssignInstantCards</d4p1:SUPageName>
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>1030</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>Swipe Funds</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:PageId>page3Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Transactions/SwipeFunds.aspx</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName />
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:DisplayOrder>1</d4p1:DisplayOrder>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>1031</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>Bulk Unload</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:MenuParentID>1030</d4p1:MenuParentID>
          <d4p1:PageId>page3Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Transactions/SwipeFunds.aspx</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName>iconSwipeFunds</d4p1:SUPageName>
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>1040</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>Transfer</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:PageId>page4Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Transactions/Transfer.aspx</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName />
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:DisplayOrder>1</d4p1:DisplayOrder>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>1041</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>External Transfer</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:MenuParentID>1040</d4p1:MenuParentID>
          <d4p1:PageId>page4Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Transactions/ExternalTranfers.aspx</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName>IconExtarnal</d4p1:SUPageName>
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:DisplayOrder>2</d4p1:DisplayOrder>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>1042</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>B2B</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:MenuParentID>1040</d4p1:MenuParentID>
          <d4p1:PageId>page4Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Transactions/BusinessToBusinessTranfers.aspx</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName>iconB2B</d4p1:SUPageName>
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:DisplayOrder>3</d4p1:DisplayOrder>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>1043</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>View Transfers</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:MenuParentID>1040</d4p1:MenuParentID>
          <d4p1:PageId>page4Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Transactions/ViewTransfers.aspx</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName>iconViewTransfers</d4p1:SUPageName>
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>1050</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>Activity</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:PageId>page5Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Transactions/Activity.aspx</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName />
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:DisplayOrder>1</d4p1:DisplayOrder>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>1051</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>Transactions History</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:MenuParentID>1050</d4p1:MenuParentID>
          <d4p1:PageId>page5Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Transactions/TransactionHistory.aspx</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName>iconTransactions</d4p1:SUPageName>
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:DisplayOrder>2</d4p1:DisplayOrder>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>1052</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>Business Statements</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:MenuParentID>1050</d4p1:MenuParentID>
          <d4p1:PageId>page5Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Transactions/BusinessStatements.aspx</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName>iconStatements</d4p1:SUPageName>
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>1060</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>Policy Management</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:PageId>page6Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Business/PolicyManagement.aspx</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName />
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:DisplayOrder>1</d4p1:DisplayOrder>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>1061</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>Expense Rules</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:MenuParentID>1060</d4p1:MenuParentID>
          <d4p1:PageId>page6Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Business/BusinessExpenseRules.aspx</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName>iconExpenseRules</d4p1:SUPageName>
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:DisplayOrder>2</d4p1:DisplayOrder>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>1062</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>Expense Categories</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:MenuParentID>1060</d4p1:MenuParentID>
          <d4p1:PageId>page6Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Business/ExpenseCategories.aspx</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName>iconExpenseCategories</d4p1:SUPageName>
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:DisplayOrder>3</d4p1:DisplayOrder>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>1063</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>Alerts Thresholds</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:MenuParentID>1060</d4p1:MenuParentID>
          <d4p1:PageId>page6Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Business/AlertsThresholds.aspx</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName>iconAlertsThresholds</d4p1:SUPageName>
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>1070</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>Reports</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:PageId>page7Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Reports/Reports.aspx</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName />
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:DisplayOrder>1</d4p1:DisplayOrder>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>1071</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>Business Account</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:MenuParentID>1070</d4p1:MenuParentID>
          <d4p1:PageId>page7Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Reports/BusinessReports.aspx?R=1</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName>iconBusinessAccount</d4p1:SUPageName>
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:DisplayOrder>2</d4p1:DisplayOrder>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>1072</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>Card Management</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:MenuParentID>1070</d4p1:MenuParentID>
          <d4p1:PageId>page7Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Reports/BusinessReports.aspx?R=2</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName>iconCardManagement</d4p1:SUPageName>
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:DisplayOrder>3</d4p1:DisplayOrder>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>1073</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>Expense Analysis</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:MenuParentID>1070</d4p1:MenuParentID>
          <d4p1:PageId>page7Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Reports/BusinessReports.aspx?R=3</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName>iconExpenseAnalysis</d4p1:SUPageName>
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>1080</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>Administration</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:PageId>page8Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Administrator/Administration.aspx</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName />
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:DisplayOrder>4</d4p1:DisplayOrder>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>1081</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>Alerts Setup</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:MenuParentID>1080</d4p1:MenuParentID>
          <d4p1:PageId>page8Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Administrator/AlertsSetup.aspx</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName>iconAlert</d4p1:SUPageName>
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:DisplayOrder>2</d4p1:DisplayOrder>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>1082</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>User Management</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:MenuParentID>1080</d4p1:MenuParentID>
          <d4p1:PageId>page8Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Administrator/UserManagement.aspx</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName>iconUserManagement</d4p1:SUPageName>
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:DisplayOrder>1</d4p1:DisplayOrder>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>1083</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>Create User</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:MenuParentID>1080</d4p1:MenuParentID>
          <d4p1:PageId>page8Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Administrator/CreateUser.aspx</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName>iconCreateUser</d4p1:SUPageName>
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:DisplayOrder>3</d4p1:DisplayOrder>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>1084</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>Update Profile</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:MenuParentID>1080</d4p1:MenuParentID>
          <d4p1:PageId>page8Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Administrator/UpdateProfile.aspx</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName>iconUpdateProfile</d4p1:SUPageName>
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:DisplayOrder>1</d4p1:DisplayOrder>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>1091</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>Card Home</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:MenuParentID>1001</d4p1:MenuParentID>
          <d4p1:PageId>page1Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Cards/CardHome.aspx</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName>iconHome</d4p1:SUPageName>
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:DisplayOrder>2</d4p1:DisplayOrder>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>1092</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>Fund Card</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:MenuParentID>1001</d4p1:MenuParentID>
          <d4p1:PageId>page1Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Cards/FundCard.aspx</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName>iconFundCard</d4p1:SUPageName>
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:DisplayOrder>3</d4p1:DisplayOrder>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>1093</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>Expense Rules</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:MenuParentID>1001</d4p1:MenuParentID>
          <d4p1:PageId>page1Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Cards/CardsExpenseRules.aspx</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName>iconExpenseRules</d4p1:SUPageName>
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:DisplayOrder>4</d4p1:DisplayOrder>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>1094</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>Cards Statements</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:MenuParentID>1001</d4p1:MenuParentID>
          <d4p1:PageId>page1Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Cards/CardsStatements.aspx</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName>iconStatements</d4p1:SUPageName>
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:DisplayOrder>5</d4p1:DisplayOrder>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>1095</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>Card Profile</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:MenuParentID>1001</d4p1:MenuParentID>
          <d4p1:PageId>page1Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Cards/CardProfile.aspx</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName>iconCardProfile</d4p1:SUPageName>
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:DisplayOrder>1</d4p1:DisplayOrder>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>2001</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>Business Funding</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:MenuParentID>1071</d4p1:MenuParentID>
          <d4p1:PageId>page7Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Reports/BusinessReports.aspx</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName>iconBusinessAccount</d4p1:SUPageName>
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:DisplayOrder>2</d4p1:DisplayOrder>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>2002</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>Invoice Report</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:MenuParentID>1071</d4p1:MenuParentID>
          <d4p1:PageId>page7Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Reports/BusinessReports.aspx</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName>iconBusinessAccount</d4p1:SUPageName>
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:DisplayOrder>1</d4p1:DisplayOrder>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>2003</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>Cards Funding</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:MenuParentID>1072</d4p1:MenuParentID>
          <d4p1:PageId>page7Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Reports/BusinessReports.aspx</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName>iconBusinessAccount</d4p1:SUPageName>
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:DisplayOrder>2</d4p1:DisplayOrder>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>2004</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>Card Status Report</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:MenuParentID>1072</d4p1:MenuParentID>
          <d4p1:PageId>page7Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Reports/BusinessReports.aspx</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName>iconBusinessAccount</d4p1:SUPageName>
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:DisplayOrder>1</d4p1:DisplayOrder>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>2005</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>Business Expense</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:MenuParentID>1073</d4p1:MenuParentID>
          <d4p1:PageId>page7Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Reports/BusinessReports.aspx</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName>iconBusinessAccount</d4p1:SUPageName>
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:DisplayOrder>2</d4p1:DisplayOrder>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>2006</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>Employee Expense</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:MenuParentID>1073</d4p1:MenuParentID>
          <d4p1:PageId>page7Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Reports/BusinessReports.aspx</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName>iconBusinessAccount</d4p1:SUPageName>
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:DisplayOrder>3</d4p1:DisplayOrder>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>2007</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>Employee By Spending Category</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:MenuParentID>1073</d4p1:MenuParentID>
          <d4p1:PageId>page7Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Reports/BusinessReports.aspx</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName>iconBusinessAccount</d4p1:SUPageName>
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:DisplayOrder>4</d4p1:DisplayOrder>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>2008</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>Merchant Expense</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:MenuParentID>1073</d4p1:MenuParentID>
          <d4p1:PageId>page7Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Reports/BusinessReports.aspx</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName>iconBusinessAccount</d4p1:SUPageName>
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:DisplayOrder>5</d4p1:DisplayOrder>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>2009</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>Spend By Transaction</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:MenuParentID>1073</d4p1:MenuParentID>
          <d4p1:PageId>page7Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Reports/BusinessReports.aspx</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName>iconBusinessAccount</d4p1:SUPageName>
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:DisplayOrder>6</d4p1:DisplayOrder>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>2010</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>Declined Transaction</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:MenuParentID>1073</d4p1:MenuParentID>
          <d4p1:PageId>page7Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Reports/BusinessReports.aspx</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName>iconBusinessAccount</d4p1:SUPageName>
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:DisplayOrder>7</d4p1:DisplayOrder>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>2011</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>Expense Category Spend</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:MenuParentID>1073</d4p1:MenuParentID>
          <d4p1:PageId>page7Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Reports/BusinessReports.aspx</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName>iconBusinessAccount</d4p1:SUPageName>
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:DisplayOrder>4</d4p1:DisplayOrder>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>2012</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>Load Limits</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:MenuParentID>1060</d4p1:MenuParentID>
          <d4p1:PageId>page6Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Business/BusinessLoadLimits.aspx</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName>iconBusinessLoadLimits</d4p1:SUPageName>
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:DisplayOrder>6</d4p1:DisplayOrder>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>2013</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>Load Limits</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:MenuParentID>1001</d4p1:MenuParentID>
          <d4p1:PageId>page1Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Cards/CardLoadLimits.aspx</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName>iconCardLoadLimits</d4p1:SUPageName>
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:DisplayOrder>7</d4p1:DisplayOrder>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>2014</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>Create Virtual Card</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:MenuParentID>1001</d4p1:MenuParentID>
          <d4p1:PageId>page1Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Cards/CreateSecondaryCard.aspx?Type=1</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName>iconCreateVirtualCard</d4p1:SUPageName>
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:DisplayOrder>8</d4p1:DisplayOrder>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>2015</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>View Virtual Cards</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:MenuParentID>1001</d4p1:MenuParentID>
          <d4p1:PageId>page1Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Cards/CreateSecondaryCard.aspx?Type=0</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName>iconViewVirtualCards</d4p1:SUPageName>
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
      </d3p1:MenuPermissions>
    </Value>
    <RoleId xmlns="">6</RoleId>
    <UserId xmlns="">manager1</UserId>
    <ClientId xmlns="">1000</ClientId>
    <FirstName xmlns="">first</FirstName>
    <LastName xmlns="">name</LastName>
  </KeyValueOfApplicationEnumApplicationPermissionscE6Yi1yY>
</ArrayOfKeyValueOfApplicationEnumApplicationPermissionscE6Yi1yY>
```

I am doing following thing but not get desire result.also i have gone through some links

```
DECLARE @INPUTUpdateUser AS [UTT_RolePermissions]
    INSERT INTO @INPUTUpdateUser  
    SELECT MenuId
    FROM OPENXML(@iXML, '/d:ArrayOfKeyValueOfApplicationEnumApplicationPermissionscE6Yi1yY/KeyValueOfApplicationEnumApplicationPermissionscE6Yi1yY/Key/Value/d3p1:MenuPermissions/d4p1:MenuItem', 3) 
    --FROM OPENXML(@iXML, '//MenuItem', 2) 
    WITH (MenuId DECIMAL(18,0))
    EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @iXML
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '
<ArrayOfKeyValueOfApplicationEnumApplicationPermissionscE6Yi1yY xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
  <KeyValueOfApplicationEnumApplicationPermissionscE6Yi1yY>
    <Key>CoreAdmin</Key>
    <Value xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CC.CoreServices.DTO.ServiceMethodResponses">
      <d3p1:MenuPermissions xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CC.CoreServices.DTO">
        <d4p1:MenuItem>
          <d4p1:IsChecked>true</d4p1:IsChecked>
          <d4p1:MenuId>1001</d4p1:MenuId>
          <d4p1:MenuName>Business Home</d4p1:MenuName>
          <d4p1:PageId>page1Link</d4p1:PageId>
          <d4p1:PageName>../Business/BusinessHome.aspx</d4p1:PageName>
          <d4p1:PageUsedBy>CoreAdmin</d4p1:PageUsedBy>
          <d4p1:SUPageName>iconHome</d4p1:SUPageName>
        </d4p1:MenuItem>
      </d3p1:MenuPermissions>
    </Value>
  </KeyValueOfApplicationEnumApplicationPermissionscE6Yi1yY>
</ArrayOfKeyValueOfApplicationEnumApplicationPermissionscE6Yi1yY>'

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(
    'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays' AS p1,
    'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CC.CoreServices.DTO.ServiceMethodResponses' AS d3p1,
    'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CC.CoreServices.DTO' AS d4p1)
SELECT t.c.value('.', 'INT')
FROM @xml.nodes('*/*/p1:Value/d3p1:MenuPermissions/d4p1:MenuItem/d4p1:MenuId') t(c)
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you have done. I mean the logic behind parsing.

Comment: When deal with `XML` schema need to declare the namespace prefixes so that they are available in the query execution context. Check about `XMLNAMESPACES` on `MSDN`